# Java string inside string to string

Tags: java, string

I have this string: `"\"Blah \'Blah\' Blah\""`. There is another string inside it. How do I convert that into: `Blah 'Blah' Blah`? (you see, unescaping the string.) This is because I get a SQL Where query:

```
WHERE blah="Blah \'Blah\' Blah"
```

When I parse this, I get the string above (still inside quotes and escaped.) How would I extract that, un-escaping the string? Or is ther some much easier way to do this? Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: are you building the sql where clause in a string, or are you using a parameterized query?

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you liked strings so we put a string inside your string so you can parse while you parse

Comment: Do you want to un-escape the double quotes as well (which are at the start and end of your example) or just the single quotes (in the middle). Also, what sort of SQL are you using, because you may need to re-escape the quotes for SQL.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## DO NOT DO THIS.

Follow the proper steps for parametrization of a query on your Database/Platform, and you won't have to escape anything. You also will protect yourself from injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: No, you see, I am not the one who creates the SQL query, it is my job to parse it. I have a SQL interface to a web service, and I have the parametrization part done, but for those people who don't like that, and do it the bad way, I have to support it. I guess I could just throw a exception, but I would like to fully support it.

Comment: Then your web service interface is broken. It should take the query and the queries parameters as separate items.

Comment: It does! That is the preferred way! But, to fully support SQL, I must support the strings directly in the query. It is bad, I agree, but I must.

Comment: I'd do that. Force the consumers to use your service properly.

Comment: I'd have to agree with this answer and encourage you to reject the request.

Comment: If you need to parse SQL, create a "real" parser and lexer, decoding the string one character at a time, into tokens and then create a syntax tree.

Answer (score 0):

Put the string in a property file, Java supports XML property files and the quote character does not need to be escaped in XML.

Use loadFromXML(InputStream in) method of the Properties class.

You can then use the MessageFormat class to interpolate values into the String if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This should be about right. This assumes that if it starts with a quote, it ends with a quote.

```
if (val.startsWith("\"") || val.startsWith("\'")) 
   val = val.substring(1, val.length-2);
```

You may wish to add `val = val.trim();` as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
"\"Blah \'Blah\' Blah\"".replaceAll("\"", "")
```

Comment: If the string was "\"Blah \\"Blah\\" Blah\"", it would come out wrong: Blah \Blah\ Blah.